# Event handling response to Edittext

Tags: java, android, char

I have a question regarding a method related to `TextWatcher` interface.

In this method `public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int Start, int before, int count)` why do we use `CharSequene` when we are dealing with numbers as ex: in the EditText box I will enter number and not characters.

Also, is there any other method which can be used otherwise ?

Answer (score 0):

> why do we use CharSequene when we are dealing with numbers

This method isn't limited to EditTexts that only accept numbers, TextWatchers will return the contents of any EditText.  You could write your own method that anticipates only numbers, but that will probably be slower than constraining the EditText to numbers-only and trying `Integer.valueOf(s)` (or `Float` or whatever) and catching any exceptions.

> Also, is there any other method which can be used otherwise ?

There are two basic ways of getting the text from an EditText, `getText()` and using a TextWatcher.  There is no built-in method that handles numbers only.